# Chrome local storage deleting after NWJS application closes on Windows

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-chrome-app, node-webkit

I have an application which uses Chrome local storage to save some information on user's pc.

This application works fine on OS X and Linux (Ubuntu), however when testing on Windows 8.1, I opened the local storage folder of the application. There were 2 files called:

```
chrome-extension_nbcogalgoagjhkbkpjfkfcckdmochgmi_0.localstorage
chrome-extension_nbcogalgoagjhkbkpjfkfcckdmochgmi_0.localstorage-journal
```

Once I closed my app I saw on the folder that both files got deleted!

After that I opened application again and found that now it created this files:

```
chrome-extension_cobbbbdapgeflbdpmchapmffabihofip_0.localstorage
chrome-extension_cobbbbdapgeflbdpmchapmffabihofip_0.localstorage-journal
```

And once again after closing application they both got deleted.

I'm using NWJS SDK 13 alpha version 3 because we're working with Chrome Serial too.

This is an issue happening only in Windows, haven't tested on other versions of Windows yet, but at least on Windows 8.1 it is, when I checked Local Storage folders on OS X and Ubuntu, files didn't got deleted.

I'm executing it in Administrator mode.

I also noticed it doesn't deletes after closing the app but after opening it again.

Not sure which files' code I should post so I'll post what I think might help. I haven't programmed in JS a lot, neither with NWJS. Probably I'm doing something wrong and because I don't know what might be useful or what not I'm not confident on making an MCVE...

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello World",
  "version": "2.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/images/16x16.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["serial"]
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
    "main": "main.html",
    "name": "PAGUSS",
    "description": "Paguss Payment Services",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "keywords": [ "paguss", "payment" ],
    "window": {
        "title": "Paguss",
        "transparent": true,
        "icon": "assets/images/64x64.png",
        "toolbar": false,
        "frame": true,
        "resizable": true,
        "position": "mouse",
        "min_width": 400,
        "min_height": 500,
        "max_width": 1200,
        "max_height": 800,
        "no-edit-menu": false
    },
    "webkit": {
        "plugin": false
    }
}
```

The first function executed when login.js is called:

```
function recoverBusinessConf(){

    var obj = {
        "id": "1",
        "saleExecutorFlow" : "[{\"callback\": \"validateTransactionData\"},{\"callback\": \"getTid\"},{\"callback\": \"fillTransactionData\"},{\"callback\": \"parseJsonToXML\"},{\"callback\": \"sendRequest\"},{\"callback\": \"processResponse\"},{\"callback\": \"endTransaction\"},{\"callback\": \"printVoucher\"},{\"callback\": \"updateLastRecordNumber\"},{\"callback\": \"sendTransactionToPagussServer\"}]",
        "name": "SOFIA IS",
        "rfc": "SIS141707UPT",
        "address": {
            "street": "CASTILLA 136",
            "cologne": "ALAMOS",
            "city": "BENITO JUÁREZ",
            "country": "MÉXICO",
            "postalCode": "03020",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": "",
            "zone": "DISTRITO FEDERAL"
        },
        "additionalData": {
            "reference": false,
            "waiter": false,
            "turn": false,
            "room": false
        },
        "product": {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "RETAIL",
            "operatives": {
                "sale": {
                    "menu-link": "",
                    "title": "Venta",
                    "voucher": "",
                    "elavonMessage": "{\"Request\": {\"_id\":\"Credit Card.Sale\",\"Version\":\"4018\",\"Block\":[{\"_id\":\"HD\",\"Network_Status_Byte\":\"*\",\"Transaction_Code\":\"000\",\"Application_ID\":\"${vendorId}\",\"Terminal_ID\":\"${affiliationAndTid}\",\"Device_Tag\":\"${serialNumber}\"},{\"_id\":\"01\",\"POS_Entry_Capability\":\"04\",\"Account_Entry_Mode\":\"${accountEntryMode}\",\"Partial_Auth_Indicator\":\"0\",\"Account_Data\":\"${track02}\",\"Transaction_Amount\":\"${elavonFormattedAmount}\",\"Last_Record_Number\":\"${lastRecordNumber}\"},{\"_id\":\"03\",\"Merchant_Reference_Nbr\":\"${merchantReferenceNumber}\"},{\"_id\":\"16\",\"ICC_Cryptogram\":\"${_9F26}\",\"ICC_CID\":\"${_9F27}\",\"ICC_AED\":\"000000\",\"ICC_Unpredictable_Number\":\"${_9F37}\",\"ICC_ATC\":\"${_9F36}\",\"ICC_TVR\":\"${_95}\",\"ICC_TT\":\"${_9C}\",\"ICC_AIP\":\"${_82}\",\"ICC_TCP\":\"${_9F33}\",\"ICC_CVMR\":\"${_9F34}\",\"ICC_TTD\":\"${_9A}\",\"ICC_Transaction_Currency\":\"${_5F2A}\",\"ICC_Authorized_Amount\":\"${_9F02}\",\"ICC_Other_Amount\":\"${_9F03}\",\"ICC_Terminal_Type\":\"${_9F35}\",\"ICC_CSN\":\"${_5F34}\",\"ICC_IAD\":\"${_9F10}\"}]}}",
                    "voucher": ["A@logo1 Santader @br @cnn VENTA @br @cnn (_affiliation_number_) _business_name_ @cnn _address_street_ @cnn _address_cologne_, _address_city_ @cnn _address_zone_ @br @lnn No.Tarjeta: _ccnumber_ @br @lnn _ccvendor_ @br @lnn APROBADA @lnn IMPORTE @cnn $ _amount_ _currency_ @br @lnn Oper.: _id_  @lnn Ref.: _reference_ @lnn ARQC: _arqc_ @lnn AID: _aid_ @lnn Aut.: _auth_ @br @lnn Fecha: _date_ _time_ @br @cnn ME OBLIGO EN LOS TERMINOS DADOS AL REVERSO DE ESTE DOCUMENTO @br @br @br @br @cnn ______________________________ @cnn _ccname_ @bc _id_ @br @br @br @br @br @br @br",
                                "A@logo1 Santader @br @cnn VENTA @br @cnn (_affiliation_number_) _business_name_ @cnn _address_street_ @cnn _address_cologne_, _address_city_ @cnn _address_zone_ @br @lnn No.Tarjeta: _ccnumber_ @br @lnn _ccvendor_ @br @cnn C-L-I-E-N-T-E @br @lnn APROBADA @lnn IMPORTE @cnn $ _amount_ _currency_ @br @lnn Oper.: _id_  @lnn Ref.: _reference_ @lnn ARQC: _arqc_ @lnn AID: _aid_ @lnn Aut.: _auth_ @br @lnn Fecha: _date_ _time_ @br @cnn ME OBLIGO EN LOS TERMINOS DADOS AL REVERSO DE ESTE DOCUMENTO @br @br @br @br @cnn ______________________________ @cnn _ccname_ @bc _id_ @br @br @br @br @br @br @br"]
                }
            }
        },
        "installer": {
        },
        "keyAccountManager": {
        },
        "affiliation": [{
            "affiliation": "7749517",
            "lastRecordNumber": 0,
            "device": {
                "serie": "",
                "model": "",
                "version": "",
                "tids": ["001"]
            },
            "paymentModes": [{
                "type": "C",
                "text": "Contado",
                "max": 1000.0,
                "min": 10.0,
                "active": true,
                "iniDate": "01/11/2015 9:00",
                "endDate": "01/12/2015 9:00"
            }],
            "currency": "MXN"
        }],
        "users": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Ricardo",
            "active": true,
            "lastName": "Vargas",
            "mothersName": "Flores",
            "mail": "fjbleal@gmail.com",
            "masterPin": "3579"
        }]
    };

    chrome.storage.local.set({'business': obj},function(items){
        window.location.href = '/view/index.html'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today was released the alpha 6 version of NWJS at Google groups, you can check it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nwjs-general/l-vc2U9mSsA). This bug was actually solved with this update:

> ## Changes (features ported from nw12)
>
> - nwjc: compile JS to machine code for source code protection
> - nw.Tray fix
> - 'single-instance' support ('true' only)
> - 'user-agent' in manifest
> - 'dom_storage_quota' and 'additional_trust_anchors' in manifest
> - Fix 'child_process.fork'
> - Fix: unable to launch in some Linux distributions
> - nw.App methods: argv, clearCache, setProxyConfig,  addOriginAccessWhitelistEntry, removeOriginAccessWhitelistEntry, part 
>     of 'open' event
> - **support migrating localstorage data file on app start**
> - nw-gyp updated to 0.13.0: Fix native module build support

So, it was a bug of the alpha version I was using and was solved today.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome app settings (on Windows at least) are stored in `Local App Settings\****app-id****\` and `Sync App Settings\****app-id****\` in a Chrome user profile, not in that `.localstorage` file which is *probably* created only temporarily for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Alright, but, why isn't Local Storage saving anything on Windows only, if it's working fine on Linux and OS X? Do you need more information? Which kind of code and I'll look for it

Comment: It's working fine on Windows. Why do  you think it doesn't?

Comment: My application checks if there's some data stored at Chrome Local Storage (It's a NWJS based app), if there isn't, then it asks user to input an ID and a key (imagine user and password) and some other configurations. Once they have completely configured it if they close / log out of app, they should be able to see a login screen (which is working fine on Linux and OS X) but on Windows it just returns me to the "register screen" instead of "login screen".

Comment: This is the route where I'm seeing the issue above commented `C:\Users\Jesus\AppData\Local\Paguss\User Data\Default\Local Storage` where `Paguss` is the app name...

Comment: You overcomplicate, there's no need to even look at the internal file structure. Show the code you use to read and write the values, and manifest.json (which btw lacks `"storage"` permission) - it's all that's needed in the question.